# Something Missing in the Triple Cross Product?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, inner-products, cross-product

I watched a [video](https://youtu.be/b7JTVLc_aMk?t=860) about vector triple product expansion. They were proving it. At the end of the video they obtained the following formula which you can access it by the
[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xH9Ep.png).

According to formula, $$\vec a×(\vec b×\vec c)=\vec b(\vec a·\vec c)-\vec c(\vec a·\vec b)$$ Also this is always equals $0$ because $\vec b(\vec a·\vec c)$ and $\vec c(\vec a·\vec b)$ are identical. Am I wrong or is video wrong?

Comment: No. $a\cdot c$ is a scalar, so this $b(a\cdot c)$ is a scalar multiple of $b$. Similarly, $c(a\cdot b)$ is a scalar multiple of $c$.

Comment: Have you read the Wikipedia article [Triple product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product)? Have you tried to compute the value of $\vec i×(\vec j×\vec k)$?

Comment: @Somos Yeah. I saw that formula is true by the calculations. But now I know that my statement was wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your statement that "$\vec{b}(\vec{a}\cdot\vec{c})$ and $\vec{c}(\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b})$ are identical" is simply WRONG!  The first is a vector in the same direction as $\vec{b}$ and the second is a vector in the same direction as $\vec{a}$.

Answer (score 1):

In short, $\vec{b}(\vec{a} \cdot \vec{c})$ is not the same as $\vec{c}(\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b})$, because $\vec{a} \cdot \vec{c}$ and $\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b}$ are scalers, not vectors.

If $a$, $b$ and $c$ are scalers, then

$b(a \cdot c) = b(ac) = bac = cab = c(ab) = c(a \cdot b)$

But, the same is not true for vectors. If we did the same with vectors (in this case $\vec{a}$, $\vec{b}$ and $\vec{c}$), then $\vec{b}(\vec{a} \cdot \vec{c})$ would be $\vec{b}$ multiplied by the scaler $\vec{a} \cdot \vec{c}$ and $\vec{c}(\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b})$ would be the same as $\vec{c}$ multiplied by $\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b}$. (If you're not sure about why these are scalers, you can look at "Dot products and duality | Chapter 9, Essence of linear algebra", a good video by  3Blue1Brown or just Google the definition of dot products.)

Therefore, it is not true that $\vec{b}(\vec{a} \cdot \vec{c}) = \vec{c}(\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b})$ for all vectors $\vec{a}$, $\vec{b}$ and $\vec{c}$, because $\vec{b}$ isn't the same as $\vec{c}$ multiplied by a scaler for all $\vec{b}$ and $\vec{c}$. (Just to be clear, that's not to say anything about whether $\vec{b}(\vec{a} \cdot \vec{c}) = \vec{c}(\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b})$ holds for some values of $\vec{b}$ and $\vec{c}$, if $\vec{b}$ was $\vec{c}$ multiplied by a scaler.)